# Rails Server - uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I'm trying to run rails s but I'm getting this error message:

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /vagrant/src/quotesgenerator/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /vagrant/src/quotesgenerator/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from /vagrant/src/quotesgenerator/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /vagrant/src/quotesgenerator/config.ru:in `new'
        from /vagrant/src/quotesgenerator/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I added gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/rails/version' as explained in this post, but it didn't solve the issue: 
**[Cannot launch rails server - uninitialized constants Sprockets::Rails::VERSION::(NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021236/cannot-launch-rails-server-uninitialized-constants-sprocketsrailsversion)**

**I'm now getting this error when running rails server:**

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- sprockets/rails/version (LoadError)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
        from /vagrant/src/quotesgenerator/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any advice how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'`

If that doesn't work try using the sprockets gem directly:

`gem 'sprockets'`